# Python Dataframe-How to groupby three different columns consisting Year, Month, Day data and calculate sum from fourth column

Tags: python, dataframe

My dataframe is given below:

```
input_df = 
index  Year  Month  Day  Hour  Minute  GHI
0     2017      1    1     7      30   100
1     2017      1    1     8      30   200
2     2017      1    2     9      30   300
3     2017      1    2    10      30   400
4     2017      2    1    11      30   500
5     2017      2    1    12      30   600
6     2017      2    2    13      30   700
```

I want to sum each day GHI data. From above I am expecting an output like below:

```
result_df = 
    index  Year  Month  Day    GHI
    0     2017      1    1     300
    1     2017      1    2     700
    2     2017      2    1     1100
    3     2017      2    2     700
```

My code and my present output is:

```
result_df = input_df.groupby(['Year','Month','Day'])['GHI'].sum()
print(result_df)
result_df = 
    index  Year  Month  Day    GHI
    0     2017      1    1     1400
    1     2017      2    2     1400
```

My above code is combining first day in each month and summing the data. But it is wrong. How to overcome it?

Comment: You are very close. This works: df_group = df.groupby(['Year', 'Month', 'Day'])['GHI'].sum().reset_index()

Comment: @KRKirov You are just great. Thanks a lot. It worked. Could you answer my question?

Comment: Sure. Here it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incredibly close in your attempt. The thing to bear in mind is that pd.groupby() has a parameter as_index with default value True. Therefore your groupby() outputs a multi-index data frame. To get the desired output you can either chain the reset_index() method after the groupby or change the value of the as_index parameter to False.

```
result_df = input_df.groupby(['Year','Month','Day'])['GHI'].sum()

result_df
Out[12]: 
Year  Month  Day
2017  1      1       300
             2       700
      2      1      1100
             2       700
Name: GHI, dtype: int64

# Getting the desired output
input_df.groupby(['Year','Month','Day'])['GHI'].sum().reset_index()
Out[16]: 
   Year  Month  Day   GHI
0  2017      1    1   300
1  2017      1    2   700
2  2017      2    1  1100
3  2017      2    2   700

input_df.groupby(['Year','Month','Day'], as_index=False)['GHI'].sum()
Out[17]: 
   Year  Month  Day   GHI
0  2017      1    1   300
1  2017      1    2   700
2  2017      2    1  1100
3  2017      2    2   700
```